# Android how to check an activity is opened from other activity

Tags: android

I have a `MainActivity` where i receive a notification in the broadcast receiver. I also have an action bar icon in main activity which opens an other activity in a small window overlayed on `MainActivity`.

When this overlayed activity is opened, I dont need to receive the notification. How do I check from my `MainActivity` that an other activity is opened(in foreground) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName;
```